# Change Drivers 13.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04

I have just upgraded to 13.04, and i'm noticing that the graphics aren't as smooth as they were in 12.04, and there is no driver option in the settings menu. Is there a way to change the driver? I have an Nvidia Quadro nvs 135M and I used the "recommended" driver for it in the additional drivers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just found out how to:
Go into 'Software & Updates" it will open the settings window. The additional drivers tab is there, click on it, and choose the driver to be used.